# How to format decimal to truncate all zeros in decimal places except the first two?

Tags: c#, .net, decimal

I'd like to achieve the following results for input in C#. How to do that?

10.000000 -> 10.00
10.200000 -> 10.20
10.254550 -> 10.25455

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
value.ToString("0.00####################");
```

Prints exactly what you need for all your sample inputs.

Both `0` and `#` are part of custom numeric format pattern. You can read what they mean on msdn: [Custom Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
string s = "10.254550";
        Response.Write(Convert.ToDecimal(s).ToString("#.00##"));
```

## `#` will consider only digits except zero